# Replace ~ symbol with text in the next cell

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to replace ~ with a word in the next or previous cell.

I have a sheet with 2 columns, columns D and E.

I would like some piece of code that sees there is a ~ symbol and when it sees this symbol is should replace the ~ automatically with the data in the next cell or previous cell.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you started.

Adjust it to fit your needs

```
Public Sub ReplaceData()

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NameOfSheet")
    
    Dim firstRow As Long
    firstRow = 2
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim evalRange As Range
    Set evalRange = targetSheet.Range("D" & firstRow & ":D" & lastRow)
    
    Dim evalCell As Range
    For Each evalCell In evalRange
        
        If evalCell.Value <> vbNullString And evalCell.Offset(0, 1).Value <> vbNullString Then
            Select Case True
            Case Asc(evalCell.Value) = Asc("~")
                evalCell.Value = evalCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Case Asc(evalCell.Offset(0, 1).Value) = Asc("~")
                evalCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = evalCell.Value
            End Select
        End If
        
    Next evalCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Ricardo Diaz, I'll play around with it!

Comment: Well, that was perfect Ricardo Diaz, just had to edit one thing but it's working perfectly! Thanks again!